# C# - How to convert Lazy<List<T>> to Lazy<List<U>>?

Tags: c#, list, lazy-loading, type-conversion

I have a `Lazy<List<T>>` where T is a class which has a huge string and metadata about files.
Let's call them Property `HugeString` and Property `Metadata`

I have this class U, which has the same property `HugeString`, among other things. I have to convert `Lazy<List<T>>` to `Lazy<List<U>>` without loading all stuff.

Is it possible ?

This is where I create my list, and inside that method I get info about the file and the file itself:

```
entity.VersionedItems =
    new Lazy<List<VersionedItemEntity>>(
        () => VersionedItemEntity.GetFromTFSChanges(entity,chng.Changes));
```

This is what I want to do (commented)

```
ChangesetList.Add(
    new HistoryLogEntryModel()
    {
        Revision = changeset.Changeset.ToString(),
        Author = changeset.User,
        Date = changeset.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
        Message = changeset.Comment,
        //VersionedItems = changeset.VersionedItems
    }
```

But HistoryLogEntryModel has a different Version of VersionedItems. And I need to convert some variables.If I would convert one thing to another, it would load up everything and that would be unnecessary and slow.

Is this the right approach? How else could I achieve this?

thanks in adv.

~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to wrap the `Lazy<List<T>>` in a `Lazy<List<U>>`.

```
var uLazy = new Lazy<List<U>>(() => tLazy.Value.Select(t => (U)t).ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use some kind of extension method:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static Lazy<U> Convert<T,U>(this Lazy<T> source, Func<Lazy<T>, Lazy<U>> convert)
    {
        return convert(source);
    }
}

Lazy<List<int>> source = new Lazy<List<int>>();

Lazy<List<string>> converted = source.Convert(x => 
{ 
 return new Lazy<List<string>>()
            {
                Items = x.Items.ConvertAll<string>(i => i.ToString())
            };
});
```

I'm sure there's a tidier way to do this though.